# Value persists for RadioButtonList server side even if all the values are unchecked through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, .net

We have a radio button list on an aspx page, where there is a deafult value selected on page load. With the help of Jquery, i am de-selecting all the values of radio button list using prop = false. Now when the form post backs, the radio button list selected value still persists, same when looking into HTML there is no selected value for radio button list ID ($("#Radio1").val()). Can any one help me out setting the selected value as null through jquery.

ASPX Code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <div> 
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem ID = "btn11" Text="YES" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem ID = "btn12" Text="NO" Value="1"></asp:ListItem> </asp:RadioButtonList> 
    <asp:Button ID="btn" Text="Submit" runat="server" onclick="btn_Click"/> </div> 
</form>
```

Code-Behind:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
foreach (ListItem test1 in radio1.Items) 
{
// Code
 } 
}
```

where i am getting radio1.selectedvalue as "0" ie : "Yes" in the option. 
JQuery Code is :

```
$("#radio1 input[type=radio]").prop("checked",false)
```

Comment: try removing the `name=""` attribute - I'm 90% sure any form inputs with a name will be passed, regardless of their value.

Comment: Can you please suggest some code snippets, as i am not using name attribute in list item.

Comment: that was really all I can think of, I'm not very experienced with `aspx`